# Incorrect image reference when launching Dataflow Flex templates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We are using Dataflow Flex Templates and following this guide (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) to stage and launch jobs. This is working in our environment. However, when I SSH onto the Dataflow VM and run `docker ps` I see it is referencing the a different docker image to the one we speccify in our template (underlined in green):
[image: Running docker ps on the Dataflow VM]

The template I am launching from is as follows and jobs are created using `gcloud beta dataflow flex-template run`:

```
{
"image": "gcr.io/<MY PROJECT ID>/samples/dataflow/streaming-beam-sql:latest",
"metadata": {
    "description": "An Apache Beam streaming pipeline that reads JSON encoded messages from Pub/Sub, uses Beam SQL to transform the message data, and writes the results to a BigQuery",
    "name": "Streaming Beam SQL",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "helpText": "Pub/Sub subscription to read from.",
            "label": "Pub/Sub input subscription.",
            "name": "inputSubscription",
            "regexes": [
                ".*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "helpText": "BigQuery table spec to write to, in the form 'project:dataset.table'.",
            "is_optional": true,
            "label": "BigQuery output table",
            "name": "outputTable",
            "regexes": [
                "[^:]+:[^.]+[.].+"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"sdkInfo": {
    "language": "JAVA"
}
}
```

So I would expect the output of `docker ps` to show `gcr.io/<MY PROJECT ID>/samples/dataflow/streaming-beam-sql` as the image on Dataflow. When I launch the image from GCR to run on a GCE instance I get the following output when running `docker ps`:

[image: Custom Docker image lunched from GCR and running on a GCE istance.]

Should I expect to see the name of the image I have referenced in the Dataflow template on the Dataflow VM? Or have I missed a step somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR; You are looking in the worker VM instead of launcher VM.

In case of flex templates, when you run the job, it first creates a launcher VM where it pulls your container and runs it to generate the job graph. This VM will destroyed after this step is completed. Then the worker VM is started to actually run the generated job graph. In the worker VM there is no need for your container. Your container is used only to generate the job graph based on the parameters passed.

In your case, you are trying to search for your image in the worker VM. The launcher VM is short lived and starts with launcher-*********************. If you SSH into that VM and do `docker ps` you will be able to see your container image.

Comment: Is there a way to specify Docker image for workers too? I would love to include heavy files (ML models) inside Docker image so my ParDo can read it from disk